# Implementing a 2D recursive spatial filter using Scipy

Tags: numpy, image-processing, recursion, scipy, signal-processing

Minimally, I would like to know how to achieve what is stated in the title. Specifically, signal.lfilter seems like the only implementation of a difference equation filter in scipy, but it is 1D, as shown in the docs. I would like to know how to implement a 2D version as described by [this difference equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlusY.png). If that's as simple as "bro, use this function," please let me know, pardon my naiveté, and feel free to disregard the rest of the post.

I am new to DSP and acknowledging there might be a different approach to answering my question so I will explain the broader goal and give context for the question in the hopes someone knows how do want I want with Scipy, or perhaps a better way than what I explicitly asked for.

To get straight into it, broadly speaking I am  using vectorized computation methods (Numpy/Scipy) to implement a Monte Carlo simulation to improve upon a naive for loop. I have successfully abstracted most of my operations to array computation / linear algebra, but a few specific ones (recursive computations) have eluded my intuition and I continually end up in the digital signal processing world when I go looking for how this type of thing has been done by others (that or machine learning but those "frameworks" are much opinionated). The reason most of my google searches end up on scipy.signal or scipy.ndimage library references is clear to me at this point, and subsequent to accepting the "signal" representation of my data, I have spent a considerable amount of time (about as much as reasonable for a field that is not my own) ramping up the learning curve to try and figure out what I need from these libraries.

My simulation entails updating a vector of data representing the state of a system each period for n periods, and then repeating that whole process a "Monte Carlo" amount of times. The updates in each of n periods are inherently recursive as the next depends on the state of the prior. It can be characterized as a difference equation as linked above. Additionally this vector is theoretically indexed on an grid of points with *uneven* stepsize. Here is an example vector `y` and its theoretical grid `t`:

```
y = np.r_[0.0024, 0.004, 0.0058, 0.0083, 0.0099, 0.0133, 0.0164]
t = np.r_[0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20]
```

I need to iteratively perform numerous operations to `y` for each of n "updates." Specifically, I am computing the curvature along the curve y(t) using finite difference approximations and using the result at each point to adjust the corresponding y(t) prior to the next update. In a loop  this amounts to inplace variable reassignment with the desired update in each iteration.

```
y += some_function(y)
```

Not only does this seem inefficient, but vectorizing things seems intuitive given y is a vector to begin with. Furthermore I am interested in preserving each "updated" y(t) along the n updates, which would require a data structure of dimensions len(y) x n. At this point, why not perform the updates inplace in the array? This is wherein lies the question. Many of the update operations I have succesfully vectorized the "Numpy way" (such as adding random variates to each point), but some appear overly complex in the array world.

Specifically, as mentioned above the one involving computing curvature at each element using its neighbouring two elements, and then imediately using that result to update the next row of the array before performing its own curvature "update." I was able to implement a non-recursive version (each row fails to consider its "updated self" from the prior row) of the curvature operation using ndimage generic_filter. Given the uneven grid, I have unique coefficients (kernel weights) for each triplet in the kernel footprint (instead of always using `[1,-2,1]` for y'' if I had a uniform grid). This last part has already forced me to use a spatial filter from ndimage rather than a 1d convolution. I'll point out, something conceptually similar was discussed in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023984/combining-two-convolution-kernels) math.exchange post, and it seems to me only the third response saliently addressed the difference between mathematical notion of "convolution" which should be associative from general spatial filtering kernels that would require two sequential filtering operations or a cleverly merged kernel.

In any case this does not seem to actually address my concern as it is not about 2D recursion filtering but rather having a backwards looking kernel footprint. Additionally, I think I've concluded it is not applicable in that this only allows for "recursion" (backward looking kernel footprints in the spatial filtering world) in a manner directly proportional to the size of the recursion. Meaning if I wanted to filter each of n rows incorporating calculations on all prior rows, it would require a convolution kernel far too big (for my n anyways). If I'm understanding all this correctly, a recursive linear filter is algorithmically more efficient in that it returns (for use in computation) the result of itself applied over the previous n samples (up to a level where the stability of the algorithm is affected) using another companion vector (z). In my case, I would only need to look back one step at output signal `y[n-1]` to compute `y[n]` from curvature at `x[n]` as the rest works itself out like a cumsum. signal.lfilter works for this, but I can't used that to compute curvature, as that requires a kernel footprint that can "see" at least its left and right neighbors (pixels), which is how I ended up using generic_filter.

It seems to me I should be able to do both simultaneously with one filter namely spatial and recursive filtering; or somehow I've missed the maths of how this could be mathematically simplified/combined (convolution of multiples kernels?).

It seems like this should be a common problem, but perhaps it is rarely relevant to do both at once in signal processing and image filtering. Perhaps this is why you don't use signals libraries solely to implement a fast monte carlo simulation; though it seems less esoteric than using a tensor math library to implement a recursive neural network scan ... which I'm attempting to do right now.

**EDIT:** For those familiar with the theoretical side of DSP, I know that what I am describing, the process of designing a recursive filters with arbitrary impulse responses, is achieved by employing a mathematical technique called the z-transform which I understand is generally used for two things:

1. converting between the recursion coefficients and the frequency response
2. combining cascaded and parallel stages into a single filter

Both are exactly what I am trying to accomplish.

Also, reworded title away from FIR / IIR because those imply specific definitions of "recursion" and may be confusing / misnomer.

Comment: When image processing is mentioned the first place you have to look is OpenCV documentation. Start here for example http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/filter_2d/filter_2d.html

Comment: @percusse Thanks for the suggestion. I did not know about OpenCV and was biased towards mathematical research or scipy specific discussions in my search for an answer. Will delve into documentation for its api to see if I find an aswer.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your intro since FIR filters are non-recursive, and so is the equation you linked to. If you don't need recursion you could use [ndimage](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html), but it looks like you've already looked into that. If the issue is with getting the pixels to the right, then you should be able to get it through a change of indexing variable.

Comment: @SleuthEye perhaps I used a misnomer. most briefly my goal is to with one operation traverse an array and at each element compute something depending on directly adjacent elements *but also* on the result of this "process" at the previous element. my limited understanding tells me this is a combination of recursive filtering and spatial filtering. signal.lfiter does the recursive bit but only 1D described [here](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/tutorial/signal.html#difference-equation-filtering) and ndimage does the spatial bit most simply with convolve. Can I do both at once?